# Read subtitles from Dropbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, activex, vlc, dropbox-api

Hi i have this project where I implemented a vlc in my windows form application.I manage to make it read movies from a dropbox folder playing the URL of the video but it doesn't load the subtitles...Does anyone know how could i fix this?i just started coding in c# and i don't know much about it...

This is how i load the URL into the playlist

```
VLC.playlist.items.clear();
textBox1.Text = (string.Format("https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto/{0}?access_token={1}", file["path"], Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken));
VLC.playlist.add((textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", "%20")));`
```

Comment: Please don't use **shouting** too much while asking questions

Comment: It's unclear from your post where the issue actually is. I recommend breaking this into pieces to start debugging. For example, try pulling the Dropbox API call out first and inspecting what you get. Are you getting the data you expect from the specified file?